# Login to a webpage though pycurl should reflect in the web browser

Tags: curl, pycurl

I am logging into a `LDAP` authenticated `gerrit` instance through a `pycurl` script as shown below,

```
import pycurl
import urllib
import StringIO

def test(debug_type, debug_msg):
    if len(debug_msg) < 300:
        print "debug(%d): %s" % (debug_type, debug_msg.strip())

pf = {'username' : 'nidhi', 'password' : 'LDAP_pswd' }
fields = urllib.urlencode(pf)
pageContents = StringIO.StringIO()

p = pycurl.Curl()
p.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
p.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, './cookie_test.txt')
p.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, './cookie_test.txt')
p.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
p.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, fields)
p.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, pageContents.write)
p.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
p.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, test)
p.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://host_ip:port/login')
p.perform()

p.close() 

pageContents.seek(0)
print pageContents.readlines()
```

I know the login is successful as when I check the present users registered, the new user is also added to the list. Once logged in, I want to provide a link such that on clicking, it directly leads you to the home page, with the user logged in. But, when I try logging in through the browser after this script is run, it leads me to the login page itself as its a new session.

I want the UI to reflect the login. How do I do this?

This is the first time I am using curl extensively and need some help...